# C++ Ignore certain strings when reading file

Tags: c++, string, file, load

I'm currently trying to do the [Clique Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem) and came across an issue. I am reading a graph from a file but the file follows a particular format:

```
c   File  p_hat1500-1.clq
c   
c
p edge  1500    284923  
e 4 1
e 5 3
e 5 4
e 6 2
```

Before each line is a letter indicating what is on that line (whether it's a comment (c) or an edge (e)), I'm trying to find out how I can read the file and ignore all the elements apart from the edge numbers so that it would instead read like this:

```
4 1
5 3
5 4
6 2
```

Thus far I'm just reading the file like this:

```
ifstream file("graph.clq");
```

and loading

```
file >> n;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "removing the unnecessary parts"?  Do you mean to change that file via a program you are writing?  Do you mean to read in the file with only the edges?

Comment: I meant read the file with only the edges.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::cerr;
using std::vector;
using std::string;

vector<std::pair<int, int>> read_graph_file(const string& file);

int main() {

    auto edges = read_graph_file("input.txt");
    for (auto edge : edges) {
        cout << edge.first << " " << edge.second << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}


vector<std::pair<int, int>> read_graph_file(const string& file) {
    auto fin = std::ifstream{file.c_str()};
    if (!fin) {
        throw std::runtime_error{"Could not open file"};
    }

    auto edges = vector<std::pair<int, int>>{};

    auto input_type = char{};
    while (fin >> input_type) {
        if (input_type != 'e') {
            while (fin.get() != '\n') {}
        } else {
            auto edge = std::pair<int, int>{};
            fin >> edge.first >> edge.second;
            edges.push_back(edge);
        }
    }

    return edges;
}
```